# Prove that $n! > n^5$

Tags: factorial

I'm trying to prove that $n! > n^5$ for large enough values of n. While it seems obvious that this should be true, I have no idea how to prove it rigorously.

EDIT:

So, looking at the comments, here's what I'm thinking now. What do folks think? Is the following reasonable?

The idea is to take the limit of the ratio of $(n+1)!/n!$ vs $(n+1)^5/n^5$ to show that the former is much larger than the latter, and thus that when `n > M`, where `M` is some positive integer, $n!$ must be growing much larger than $n^5$:

Let us assume $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!} > \frac{(n+1)^5}{n^5}$

$$
\lim_{n\to\inf} \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} > \frac{(n+1)^5}{n^5}\\
= \lim_{n\to\inf} n+1 > (\frac{n+1}{n})^5\\
= \lim_{n\to\inf} n+1 > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^5\\
\ldots
=\lim_{n\to\inf} n+1 > (1 + 3/n + 8/n^2 + 10/n^3 + 5/n^4 + 1/n^5)\\
= inf > 1
$$

(Edited [again]: I did not know you could use latex)

Comment: Find a particular value satisfying the inequality. Then, you can show that it is satisfied for higher values using induction.

Comment: use 1st derivative

Comment: @David Could you explain your idea a bit more?

Comment: mfl: "good" idea you had asking me to elaborate, you got me 5 downvotes as a result.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that $n!>n^5$ is equivalent to $$(1)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{4}{n}\right)((n-5)!)>1.$$ (this is similar to anomaly's answer).

Comment: Assuming something and then showing that it implies a true statement doesn't constitute a proof. Reduce the inequality you're trying to prove to $(n + 1) > (1 + n^{-1})^{5}$, and use the fact that $1 + n^{-1} \leq 2$ for positive $n$.

Answer (score 6):

For $n \geq 10$, we have
$$n! = n(n-1) \cdots (n-4)(n - 5)! \geq \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^5 (n - 5)! = n^5\left(\frac{(n -5)!}{32}\right) > n^5.$$
(The bound above is not sharp, but it's sufficient for the problem. Also, the same argument shows that for any $p > 0$, we have $n! > n^p$ for sufficiently large $n$.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Ya, sorry, I tried to correct my comment before I read yours.

Comment: How do you show that $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) \geq (\frac{n}{2})^5$? That is not obvious to me.

Comment: Since $n\geq 10$, each term is at least $n/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way:
$n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * ... * n$.
We want to prove that it is bigger than $n^5$. That's equivalent to the statement that $n! > (\sqrt n)^{10}$. This means that if we have at least $10$ numbers in $n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n$ that are strictly greater than $\sqrt n$, the inequality becomes trivial. To illustrate, suppose for simplicity let's set $n=25$. We get $\sqrt n = 5$, so now we have in the product $25-5=20$ multipliers which are at least $\sqrt n = 5$, which is double what we need to prove the inequality.

What we did so far: $n! = 1 * 2 * ... * 5 * 6 * 7 * ... * 14 * 15 * 16 * ... * 25 = 1 * 2 * ... * \sqrt n * (\sqrt n + 1) * (\sqrt n + 2) * ... * (\sqrt n + 9) * (\sqrt n + 10) * 16 * ... * 25 > 1 * 2 * ... * \sqrt n * \sqrt n * \sqrt n * ... * \sqrt n * \sqrt n * 16 * ... * 25 > (\sqrt n)^{10} = n^5$

Generalizing this, we can write:
$n! = \prod_{k = 1}^{n}{k} = (\prod_{k = 1}^{\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor}k)(\prod_{k = \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor + 1}^{n}k) > \prod_{k = \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor + 1}^{n}\sqrt n = \sqrt n^{n - \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor} > \sqrt n^{10} = n^5$

The last inequality is only true when $n-\sqrt n > 10$, but as this goes to infinity when $n \rightarrow \infty$, for some sufficiently large $n$ (and we've seen that $5$ is sufficient), $n! > n^5$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

use induction to prove your inequality for $n\geq 8$

Answer (score 0):

Show $10!>10^5$

Assume $n!>n^5$

Prove $(n+1)!>(n+1)^5$:

- $(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$
- $n!(n+1)>n^5(n+1)$ `assumption used here`
- $n^5(n+1)=n^6+n^5$
- $n^6+n^5>n^6$
- $n^6>n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1$ `for large enough values of n`
- $n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1=(n+1)^5$

Answer (score 0):

Use a multiplicative variant of [Gauss's trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes):
$$
(n!)^2 = (1 \cdot n) (2 \cdot (n-1)) (3 \cdot (n-2)) \cdots
                ((n-2) \cdot 3) ((n-1) \cdot 2) (n \cdot 1)
                \ge n^n
$$
For $n\ge 10$, we get $n! \ge n^5$.

If you really need strict inequality, take $n=11$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is $10$ or greater,
$$\begin{align}
n!&=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)(n-7)(n-8)(n-9)!\\
&=n\big((n-1)(n-5)\big)\big((n-2)(n-6)\big)\big((n-3)(n-7)\big)\big((n-4)(n-8)\big)(n-9)!\\
&>n(n)(n)(n)(n)(n-9)!\\
&=n^5(n-9)!\\
&\geq n^5
\end{align}$$

For $n=9$, $$\frac{9!}{9^5}=\frac{8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{9^4}=\frac{8\cdot7\cdot2\cdot5\cdot4\cdot2}{9^3}=\frac{560\cdot 8}{729}>1$$ so it is still true.

For $n=8$, $$\frac{8!}{8^5}=\frac{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{8^4}=\frac{7\cdot3\cdot5\cdot3}{8^2\cdot4}=\frac{21\cdot 15}{256}>1$$ so it is still true.

For $n=7$, $$\frac{7!}{7^5}=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{7^4}=\frac{720}{49^2}<1$$ so it is no longer true.

Therefore $n!>n^5$ for all $n\geq8$.

Answer (score -1):

I find the simplest way to prove this sort of inequality is to prove that the ratio of the two sequences converges to $\infty$ or $0$ (depending on which ratio you're looking at). In other words, prove that $\frac {n!} {n^5}\to \infty$.

Answer (score -4):

The first derivative of those should be useful in your proof.  Start with n = $10$ for example.

Someone asked me to explain further but I am not a math person so it will be a simple explanation.

For n = $10$ we have $10$! vs. $10^5$ which is $3,628,800$ vs. $100,000$ so it is already larger at the point.  If we increase n to $11$, the $10$! increases by a factor of $11$ but the $10^5$ increases by $1.1^5$ which is only about $1.61$.  If we increase n to $12$ you can see a "breakaway" between them so just prove this breakaway by showing the "discrete 1st derivative" of n! is increasing greater than that of $n^5$ and you got it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me may not realize that this method actually works.  I don't like to use induction as a "proof" because it assumes stuff.  My way you can show that the derivatives are behaving predictably and from that you can draw a conclusion so perhaps you should cancel your downvote.  How the heck can you assume what you are trying to prove?  That makes no sense to me.

Comment: "I don't like to use induction as a 'proof' because it assumes stuff."?

Comment: I can agree that your method works; unfortunately for you, all things about the “discrete derivative” must be proved with induction. If induction doesn't make sense to you, probably it's better you stop doing mathematics.

Comment: Induction is not the problem for me, it is assuming the part you are trying to prove that bothers me.  It is like saying prove the moon is made out of cheese:  step 1, assume the moon is made out of cheese.  What difference does it make what I do after that?  I already assumed what I was trying to prove.  This is why I never really liked "proofs" of this form.

Comment: In an inductive proof, you're assuming a statement $P(n)$ holds for $n = n_0$ and then showing that it holds for $n = n_0 + 1$. It's not circular at all. It's a very basic, completely legitimate type of proof, and there's no reason to object to or even disprefer it. While I certainly don't want to be rude or try to dissuade you from posting, you might want to be careful about giving math advice if you have objections or problems with induction.

Comment: Look at the assumption if the post below.  It is Assume n! > $n^5$.  To me, a more "legit" proof is one that not assume what we are trying to prove.  I am not a mathematician (nor do I want to be), but my personal "take" is what I stated here.  Others may not agree with me but that is fine.  My first derivative solution works and doesn't assume anything about what we are trying to prove.

Comment: I suggest you understand induction before helping others.